# How to add an auth listener firebase without getting memory leak

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

need a little help.
i'm trying to add an auth listener to my react app, but i'm getting a memory leak, i need this listener to be active all the time so it will render the user content that is logged in, the login & register are on the same route as the user , on auth state change i am just rendering different components.

```
  state = {
    login: false
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.authListener();
  }

  authListener = () => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({
          login: true
        });
      } else this.setState({ login: false });
    });
  };

  redirectOnLogIn = () => {
    let { login } = this.state;
    if (!login) {
      return <Auth />;
    } else {
      return <Users />;
    }
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

`componentWillMount()` - this function might end up being called multiple times before the initial render is called so might result in triggering multiple side-effects. Due to this fact it is not recommended to use this function for any side-effect causing operations. Try using `componentDidMount()` and report back.
P.S. also if I were you, I would move auth.onAuthStateChanged in your app.js file -- something like this

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Users />, document.getElementById("app"));
    }
  } else {
  ReactDOM.render(<Auth />, document.getElementById("app"));
  }
});
```

Also for initial run you could add something like this before it.

`var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if(user){
    ...
    }else{
    ...
    }`

Comment: i tried it still same problem. this thing also brings me the problem that if i hard refresh the browser it will show me for a blink the login form before rendering the users content. - when logged in.

Comment: ok basically it works i just need to combine in the navbar  thanks!